# how to get a random number from fibonacci series

Tags: javascript

I want to get a random number from the Fibonacci series:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, ...

Here is my code:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
var series_element = -1;
if (number < 1) {
    series_element = 1;
} else {
    if (number < 2) {
        series_element = 2;
    } else {
        if (number < 3) {
            series_element = 3;
        } else {
            if (number < 5) {
                series_element = 5;
            } else {
                if (number < 8) {
                    series_element = 8;
                } else {
                    if (number < 13) {
                        series_element = 13;
                    } else {
                        if (number < 21) {
                            series_element = 21;
                        }
                        ////// series continues to 317811
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(series_element);
```

But I never got the value of `series_element` less than 100. It always shows me higher values.

Comment: I see a repeated pattern in your code.  And when you have a repeated pattern over and over again, it's time to make a function or a loop.

Comment: Why did you stop at 21 if the serise contine to 317811?

Comment: @destoryer it will become lengthly to add all code here so i wrote in the comment for understanding

Comment: @Amy how we can do this by using loop

Comment: @Vishalchoudhary can you clarify this `get a random number from the fibonacci series`? As your code and question does not match either

Comment: well i was thinking to pick a random number and then check the number between the range of two fibonacci series number 
for example if random in between 13 to 20 it will show me 21 and if in between 21 to 33 it will show me 34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean that you're not getting a random number less than 100 from the `Math.random()` function. So you're not getting your variable `series_element` to be 11 or less (the first 11 terms of the Fibonacci sequence: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89).

In fact, it's a matter of probabilities.

> 100 / 1000000 = 0.0001

If you keep executing it you'll get a value less than 100 at some point... approximately 1 from 10000 times you do it.

There's nothing wrong with your code, but it could be improved so you don't have to put so much ifs.

Comment: you are right i got the problem its a matter of probabilities

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define a function to calculate the fibonacci numbers. Details on how to do that can be find here: https://medium.com/developers-writing/fibonacci-sequence-algorithm-in-javascript-b253dc7e320e

```
function fibonacci(num){
  var a = 1, b = 0, temp;
  while (num >= 0){
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
  }
  return b;
}
```

To get a random Fibonacci number you can call this function with a random number.

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
var result = fibonacci(number);
```

I don't recommend going after 100 as your computer may take too much time to process the result...

Comment: "your computer may take too much time to process the result" - sure, Fibonacci function is perhaps the worst use-case ever for recursion, as you calculate the whole sequence  _twice_ for each number.

Comment: Yes, as explained in the link I provided :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using with poorly structured code to generate fabonacci series. Try something like following, you will get value under 100 and 1000 
Where `N` is position of Fibonacci number from `1` to `N` and `X` is actual number.

```js
var n = function getRandomNum() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +1;
  }

var result = [];
result[0] = 1;
result[1] = 1;

function fib(x) {
  var ix, ixLen;
  for(ix = 0, ixLen = x; ix < ixLen; ix++){
    if(!result[ix]){
      result[ix] = result[ix-2] + result[ix-1];
    }
  }
  console.log('n:', x, ' result: ', result[ix-1]);
  return result[ix-1];
}
console.log(fib(n()));
```